How can I reliably use a physical disk as a VMware guest os disk without risks?
I have a dual boot machine with two Linux installations, one is my main system and the other is a kind of a recovery installation to use in case something goes wrong with the main installation (for fixing the main one or even to use it in an emergency situation).
Since I try to keep this secondary installation up to date, it requires regularly updating packages and etc.  The problem is that this requires booting it from time to time, which is time consuming and, not to say, very annoying.
To address this, I've setup a VMware guest machine that uses the second installation physical disk as its virtual one, allowing me to maintain this second installation as a background task (most of the time).
The problem is that there are some known risks of using physical disks on VMs, being the most important ones that worth mentioning:

The possibility of booting the VM while the main OS has one or more of its partitions also mounted, often leading to corruption and data loss.
VMware to accidentally use the wrong physical disk due to the kernel uniform naming of devices not being guaranteed at each boot.  At least theoretically the same disk can be assigned to different /dev/sdX nodes on different boots.

How could I prevent this situation from happening?

In order to address the risks mentioned in the question, we will write a udev rule that makes sure VMware will always use the correct disk.  Additionally, unless if explicitly mounted by the user, it also makes sure none of its partitions will be automounted by udisks based utilities and environments (usually under /run/media/<user>/...):
You can save the file below as /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-vmdk.rules
# The purpose of these rules is to make sure vmware will use the correct phisical device as a virtual disk.
# All rules are based on the disk serial numbers, which can be obtained running:
#   "udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/<device>"
# and looking for a line like this:
#   "E: ID_SERIAL=<serial>"
#
# After editing this file with the correct serial number, execute:
#   "udevadm control --reload-rules"
#   "udevadm trigger"

# Serial and node numbers associations:
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="<serial 1...>", ENV{VMDK_NODE_NR}="0", GOTO="VMDK_MATCH"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="<serial 2...>", ENV{VMDK_NODE_NR}="1", GOTO="VMDK_MATCH"

GOTO="VMDK_END"

LABEL="VMDK_MATCH"

# Prevent udisks based automount utilities to mount the disk under "/run/media/<user>/..."
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{UDISKS_AUTO}="0"

# Create a symlinks to "/dev/vmdisk<node number>[p<partition>]"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", SYMLINK+="vmdisk$env{VMDK_NODE_NR}"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", SYMLINK+="vmdisk$env{VMDK_NODE_NR}p%n"

LABEL="VMDK_END"

Then, configure VMware to use /dev/vmdisk0 instead of the canonical name of the device (like /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, /dev/nvme0n1p1, ...).
Note that vmware will initially refuse to add a physical device if you specify a symlink as the device path.  That's ok, firstly create it using its canonical name, then close vmware and edit the vmdk file.
There should be a line there looking like this:
RW 1000215216 FLAT "/dev/sda" 0

Replace only the device name and don't touch anything else:
RW 1000215216 FLAT "/dev/vmdisk0" 0

Of course you can increase these udev rules to add more disks based on their serial numbers and name them /dev/vmdisk2, /dev/vmdisk3 ...
OBS: This has been tested on VMWare Workstation 17.5

The main purpose of posting this question was to share the techniques I developed and that can help others, so I'm answering my own question.
Any improvements and other answers that complement it are more than welcome.
